# Unable to build project : layout bounds on right border must start at edge

Tags: android

Getting this error:

```
Error:layout bounds on right border must start at edge.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
```

Comment: Solution given is not working for me.

Comment: If you are using nine-patch images, check them. At least one of them may have wrong boundaries.

Comment: I just removed red dots from all 9.png images and it compiled. Not yet sure if any run-time nightmares am going to face as result of this.What a pathetic experience of upgrading Android Studio. It wasted my hours :(